# spark streaming JSON value in dataframe column scala

Tags: json, scala, spark-streaming

I have a text file with json value. and this gets read into a DF

```
{"name":"Michael"}
{"name":"Andy", "age":30}
```

I want to infer the schema dynamically for each line while **Streaming** and store it in separate locations(tables) depending on its schema.

unfortunately while I try to read the value.schema it still shows as String. Please help on how to do it on Streaming as RDD is not allowed in streaming.

I wanted to use the following code which doesnt work as the value is still read as String format.

```
val jsonSchema = newdf1.select("value").as[String].schema
val df1 = newdf1.select(from_json($"value", jsonSchema).alias("value_new"))
val df2 = df1.select("value_new.*")
```

I even tried to use,

```
schema_of_json("json_schema"))

val jsonSchema: String = newdf.select(schema_of_json(col("value".toString))).as[String].first()
```

still no hope.. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

You can load the data as textFile, create case class for person and parse every json string to Person instance using json4s or gson, then creating the Dataframe as follows:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val jsons = spark.read.textFile("/my/input")
val persons = jsons.map{json => toPerson(json) //instead of 'toPerson' actually parse with json4s or gson to return Person instance}
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(persons)
```

Deserialize json to case class using json4s:
https://commitlogs.com/2017/01/14/serialize-deserialize-json-with-json4s-in-scala/

Deserialize json to case class using gson:
https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/scala/scala-case-class-gson-json-object-deserialization-and-scalatra

Comment: Thanks Ofek, but if I give the case class or structtype it becomes a static schema. But I want my streaming to read the data and make a dynamic schema by itself..